# google maps marker as div instead canvas

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas

is it possible to have marker rendered as div or image instead of canvas? i am trying to export current viewport of google maps into png with help of html2canvas, but i am unable to render the markers.

when i am trying this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
```

i got the following error

```
SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

PS: i use `useCORS` option in html2canvas, no problem in rendering images.

Answer (score 1):

The canvases used by Google Maps are rended by their scripts so any "useCORS" options in your own scripts are irrelevant. If Google Maps taints its canvases there isn't much you can feasibly do about that.

One way to get something similar to what you're trying to do would be to use the [Maps Images APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) which supports CORS to render a static image of the map instead of trying to render the live interface (there are limitations wrt to image size though).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know about static maps but can i export all current content like marker, path, etc from current viewport? the maps will be dynamic, in other words user can add their own marker, etc.

Comment: If you have an editor on your map surely there's a way to extract the stuff the user has added? It might get interesting trying to stuff all that into the static map URL though.